# jQuery Autocomplete / Twitter Typeahead Populate Multiple Fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm currently using TypeAhead (Bootstrap) but happy to use jQuery Autocomplete to accomplish what I need

I have 5 input fields. I also have a table structured as below so I'll be using a remote datasource:

```
Classification   | Model | Cost  | Depreciation  | Warranty
-----------------------------------------------------------
Laptop/PC/Server | X/Y/Z | 1/2/3 | 1/2/3/4/5/6/7 | 1/2/3
```

So there are multiple values for each column. A laptop can only have certain models attributed to it

**Question One**

Let's say I choose "Laptop" for an autocomplete field, is there anyway to refine the "Model" field to pick out only those models attributed with the chosen laptop?

**Question Two**

In the first instance, let's presume the above isn't possible. Let's say I chose "Laptop" from the autocomplete field for "Classification". I then go to the "Model" autocomplete field and choose for example "Latitude D830". Is there anyway I can then populate the Cost/Depreciation/Warranty field automatically?

Let's now say the first question is possible. What's the best way to combine the two? The current TypeAhead initialisation is pretty vanilla

```
$('#inputClassification').typeahead([
        {
            name: 'classification',
            local: ["Tablet", "PC", "Laptop", "Phone", "Printer", "Switch", "Router", "Firewall", "Wireless AP", "Wireless Controller", "Server", "Storage"]
        }
        ]);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes thats all possible, show us the code you have written so far.

Comment: It's just vanilla TypeAhead code (edited question). Got nowhere with any of the code I've written so just stripped it to basics. I see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309880/jquery-autocomplete-two-fields-based-on-one-field-using-php-and-mysql is close (if not spot on) to what I want but was wondering what could be done with TypeAhead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems something along these lines seems to work

```
       $('#inputLocationStatus').typeahead({
            name: 'poiuy',
            prefetch: 'js/names.json',
            ttl:0                                                             
        }).on('typeahead:selected', onSelected);

        function onSelected($e, datum) {
            $('#inputDepartment').val(datum['description']);
        }
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks Janusz.  I've been looking for this solutions for hours.