# typeahead.js doesn't display the dropdown using remote data

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I think I have around 5 hours since I'm struggling with the typeahead.js library. I'm trying to load the data using the remote functionality but I don't have any luck on making it working completely.

These are the js libraries that I'm loading:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/handlebars-v3.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
```

Then, in order to initialize my typeahead feature, I'm using this piece of code:

```
$(function () {
    var cards = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function (datum) {
            console.log(datum);
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: '/home/suggest?searchQuery=%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY',
            filter: function (response) {
                return $.map(response, function (item) {
                    return {
                        value: item.Text,
                        tokens: item.Document
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    cards.initialize();

    $(".typeahead").typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 3
    },
    {
        name: 'CardSearch',
        displayKey: 'value',
        valueKey: 'value',
        source: cards.ttAdapter()
    }).on('typeahead:render', function(ev, suggestion, isAsync, dsName) {
        console.log(suggestion, isAsync, dsName);
    }).on('typeahead:asyncreceive', function(ev, query, dsName) {
        console.log(query, dsName);
    });
});
```

From my debugging steps I realize that the remote data retrieval is working perfectly because:

a) in firefox / firebug I see the request and the response

b) I've put a `console.log` statement inside `filter` assigned function and everything is fine.

... And everything stops here... Nothing is being displayed as a dropdown list and also the hint is not working either...

What I've done next is to put some `console.log` statements on `typeahead:render` and `typeahead:asyncreceive` events and what I see is that all the parameters (except the jquery event) are `undefined`, which makes me believe that somehow, the typeahead is not being initialized correctly.

Please, if you have any idea or suggestions, give me a hint.

THANK YOU!

Later edit: This is how the generated HTML looks like:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
<form action="/Home/Search" class="navbar-form" method="get" role="search">
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control typeahead" id="query" name="query" placeholder="Search" type="text" value="" />
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538591/jquery-autocomplete-twitter-typeahead-populate-multiple-fields this of any use

Comment: No, because I'm not getting to the point of having something displayed... I see that also in the issue the data was local...

Comment: What's the HTML that sits behind this?

Comment: I updated the question also with the HTML. Thank you!

Comment: can you please create a demo on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do but I have no idea how can I simulate the `remote` scenario so I can get the JSON back from the same origin to have a 100% identical scenario.

Comment: Unfortunatelly for now I dropped this functionality to a more simpler one - instead of retrieving a complete set of data, I got from the server a list of strings (json) and now it's working. Anyway, if you take a look in the page source + js from here `http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/`, you will see that the things are a bit more complicated than described in the docs. When I will have a bit of time, I will try to make this working also and come back with a complete solution.